# Asignar valor a un date en angular 2 (binding)

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

Necesito setear/asignar una valor a una fecha de un componente especifico que es un date antes de cargue mi pagina. En este ejemplo intento asignar el primero y ultima dia del mes.

HTML:

```
<pf-input-date [(date)]="fechaHasta" mode="day" name="fechaHasta"></pf-input-date>
```

TypeScript:

```
export class LiquidoProductoComponent implements OnInit {
    fechaDesde: Date;
    fechaHasta: Date;
    date: Date;


    ngOnInit() {
        this.date = new Date();

        // Verificar
        let desde = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), 1);
        var hasta = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

 // Esta asignacion la realiza pero no asi el binding

        this.fechaDesde = desde; 
        this.fechaHasta = hasta;

    };
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr data-binding en dos direcciones necesitas un emisor de eventos con un decorador "@Output" por cada variable que quieres asociar a tu template, y con el nombre apropiado segun la variable a la que le haces el data-binding usando el sufijo "Change".

En tu ejemplo, necesitarías añadir este código a tu componente:

```
@Output() fechaDesdeChange = EventEmitter<Date>();
@Output() fechaHastaChange = EventEmitter<Date>();
```

El sufijo "Change" es por convenio, y por tanto obligatorio.

Más detalles en la página siguiente (en Inglés): 
[Angular 2 Training - Using Two-Way Data Binding](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html)